# Strange behavior in `matrix` in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm getting strange behavior where matrix dimensions are not working as expected here is a toy example

```
n <- 10     
delt <- 0.00001
s <- n/delt + 1
print(s)
```

s = 1000001

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow = s, ncol = 2)
dim(x)
```

1000000  2

However, if I type

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow = 1000001, ncol = 2)
dim(x)
```

I get what I expect 1000001  2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why:

```
print(s,digits=20L); ## s is slightly under 1000001 after all
## [1] 1000000.9999999998836
as.integer(s); ## truncates to 1000000
## [1] 1000000
```

The [documentation on `matrix()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html) doesn't explicitly say it, but the `nrow` and `ncol` arguments are internally coerced to integer.

Also see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

Comment: I see, the coercion truncates instead of rounds so have to watch out for numerical error (especially when dividing by such a small number).